# How do I debug heroku nodejs buildpack's heroku-postbuild hook?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I'm trying to have Heroku build my React project on deploy. I created a project with `create-react-app` and added a `heroku-postbuild` command to the scripts sections.

But when I push to Heroku and check the logs for the machine, nothing appears to be happening.

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "new-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "echo \"-----> Build Project\" && react-scripts build"
  }
}
```

I even tried ejecting Webpack from the project with `npm run eject` and setting the postbuild command to run Webpack, but no luck.

How can I debug this more?

Comment: Can you double-check that you've added a `nodejs` buildpack? Type `heroku buildpacks` and see if it outputs `heroku/nodejs`